# Prove: In a finite dimensional vector space, every spanning set contains a basis.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces

The following quoted text is from Evar D. Nering's *Linear Algebra and Matrix Theory, 2nd Ed.*

> Theorem 3.5. In a finite dimensional vector space, every spanning set
>   contains a basis.
>
> Proof: Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a set spanning $\mathcal{V}$. If
>   $\mathcal{V}=\{0\}$, then $\emptyset\subset\mathcal{B}$ is a basis of
>   $\{0\}$. If $\mathcal{V}\ne\{0\}$ then $\mathcal{B}$ must contain at
>   least one non-zero vector $\alpha_{1}$. We now search for another
>   vector in $\mathcal{B}$ which is not dependent on $\{\alpha_{1}\}$. We
>   call this vector $\alpha_{2}$ and search for another vector in
>   $\mathcal{B}$ which is not dependent on the linearly independent set
>   $\{\alpha_{1},\alpha_{2}\}$. We continue in this way as long as we
>   can, but the process must terminate as we cannot find more than $n$
>   linearly independent vectors in $\mathcal{B}$. Thus suppose we have
>   obtained the set $\mathcal{A}=\{\alpha_{1},\dots,\alpha_{n}\}$ with
>   the property that every vector in $\mathcal{B}$ is linearly dependent
>   on $\mathcal{A}$. Then because of Theorem 2.1 the set $\mathcal{A}$
>   must also span $\mathcal{V}$ and it is a basis.

The reasoning in the proof seems circular.  "Seek, and ye shall find." isn't very rigorous. I certainly believe that I could find such linearly independent vectors, but that's because I believe the theorem to be true.

Is the proof satisfactory?

I might be able to come up with my own proof, but I would still like to know if Nering's proof is satisfactory to mathematicians.

Comment: Formally, the theorem is missing a definition of $n$ (unless some standard notation is defined somewhere else; although it is quite clear in this context).

Comment: I don't know if this is overkill, but you could formalize this kind of sequence building argument by considering all sets of linearly independent vectors from $\mathcal{B}$ ordered by inclusion and apply Zorn's Lemma. Then any maximal element must be a basis for $V$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the proof is fine. You need not believe that you can find such linearly independent vectors. At each step, there either still exists another vector in $\mathcal B$ that is independent of what you already have (and then you *can* proceed), or there does not exist such a vector (and the process terminates). If you already know that a linearly independent set cannot have more than $\dim V$ elements, the process is doomed to terminate with some number $n\le \dim V$ vectors picked that way.
By revisiting the termination condition, those $n$ vectors span $V$, hence must be a basis.

Comment: What I find lacking is any explanation of why I should expect there to be some vector not in the current collection, but in the spanning set.  I'm not even sure what "seek" means in the mathematical sense.   I believe I came up with a valid proof which I find more satisfying.  It's too long to post as a comment.  The gist of it is that it shows that no fewer than $n$ vectors can span $\mathcal{V}$ so the difference of that set of $m<n$ vectors and $\mathcal{B}$ will be non-empty.  Select one vector from that set and go again.

Comment: I'm accepting the answer because it appears to be true that some mathematicians think the proof is satisfactory.  I still don't like it.  It seems vague, and more like an exercise than a proof.  For example, could it be expressed in the formalism of predicate logic?  I hope I don't come across as ungrateful.  I do value the feedback.  My reluctance to fully accept it may well be my shortcoming.